# What numeric values defines in dissembled of C code?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, mnemonics

I'm understanding the assembly and C code.
I have following C program , compiled to generate Object file only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  int j = 22 + i;
  return 0;
}
```

I executed following command

```
objdump -S myprogram.o
```

Output of above command is:

```
objdump -S testelf.o 

testelf.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
  int i = 10;
   6:   c7 45 f8 0a 00 00 00    movl   $0xa,-0x8(%ebp)
  int j = 22 + i;
   d:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
  10:   83 c0 16                add    $0x16,%eax
  13:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)

  return 0;
  16:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  1b:   c9                      leave  
  1c:   c3                      ret
```

What is meant by number numeric before the mnemonic commands
i.e. "83 ec 10 " before "sub" command or
     "c7 45 f8 0a 00 00 00" before "movl" command

I'm using following platform to compile this code:

```
$ lscpu 
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
```

Comment: Those are the machine code sequences that the assembly instructions were assembled into. See [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for a full instruction set reference and information on how to map instructions to machine code (and vice versa).

Comment: Note that, if you want to study the assembly output of a little test program like that, the compiler might optimize useless code away. In this case probably everything because j is never used.

Comment: Notice that this is [AT&T syntax](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm), so it does not correspond directly with the syntax represented in Intel manuals.

Comment: Basically it is setup that is positioning the stack-pointer at the top of the stack. There are no `argc` or `argv` values, so you likely have 4-bits for argc, 8-bits for argv and a 4-bit align resulting in your `0x10` offset from the top of the stack. .

Comment: The opcodes you can find [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html)

Comment: It is mentioned in the [man page for `objdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump): "When disassembling instructions, print the instruction in hex as well as in symbolic form. **This is the default** except when --prefix-addresses is used."

Answer (score 1):

Those are x86 opcodes. A detailed reference, other than the ones listed in the comments above is available [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x0FF8).

For example the `c7 45 f8 0a 00 00 00` before the `movl   $0xa,-0x8(%ebp)` are hexadecimal values for the opcode bytes. They tell the CPU to move the immediate value of 10 decimal (as a 4-byte value) into the address located on the current stack 8-bytes above the stack frame base pointer.  That is where the variable `i` from your C source code is located when your code is running. The top of the stack is at a lower memory address than the bottom of the stack, so moving a negative direction from the base is moving up the stack.

The `c7 45 f8` opcodes mean to mov data and clear the arithmetic carry flag in the [EFLAGS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) register. See the [reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x0FF8) for more detail.

The remainder of the codes are an [immediate value](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/immediate_value). Since you are using a little endian system, the least significant byte of a number is listed first, such that 10 decimal which is 0x0a in hexadecimal and has a 4-byte value of 0x0000000a  is stored as `0a 00 00 00`.