# How to get assembly instructions or mnemonics from the opcode/machine code?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, opcode

I have a binary file compiled using gcc of a simple c program.
I'm writing my own dis-assembler, I able to read ELF header and other header from ELF files.

I'm reading ".text"section from ELF binary file. And trying to convert the opecode into mnemonics/assembly instruction.

How to convert raw opcode/machine code into  mnemonics/assembly instruction??
C source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  int j = 22 + i;

  return 0;
}
```

Following is the example of raw opcode i have received after reading ELF file:

```
55 ffffff89 ffffffe5 ffffff83 ffffffec 20 ffffffc7 45 ffffffec 3 ffffffc7 45
fffffff0 41 ffffffc7 45 fffffff4 8 ffffffc7 45 fffffff8 21 ffffff8b 45
ffffffec ffffff83 ffffffc0 16 ffffff89 45 fffffffc ffffffb8 ffffffc9 ffffffc3
```

Comment: Your disassembler would probably need to include a list of all opcodes and which instructions they correspond to, and it would also have to parse all prefixes and the ModR/M and SIB bytes. You can find all this info in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: You need to fix your code so it doesn't sign-extend 8-bit values to 32-bit before printing them.

Comment: Use **`unsigned char`** to read the opcode values, and print with `%02x`.

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad, as the question asks how to write a disassembler without showing any effort towards it. ([OP is already knowledgeable of `objdump`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370689/what-numeric-values-defines-in-dissembled-of-c-code))

Comment: You use the freely available Intel instruction references.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, but I disagree with you. I was not asking for complete diassemble code, I wrote code to parse the ELF, I just need hint/pointer to decode the above formatted opcode to mnemonics.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the *GNU binutils* installed (which you likely have), you can use

```
objdump --disassemble elf-file
```

If the question is "Why do I get those ffffff numbers", then you need to show us the code that produces the numbers. Most likely you are having a sign extension issue from signed characters to int.

Comment: Of course [they have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370689/what-numeric-values-defines-in-dissembled-of-c-code)